# Grav CMS links in css

Tags: html, css, frontend, assets, grav

I have a problem with adding the custom fonts in Grav CMS. All fonts are added under the folder path: user/themes/bildxwerkstatt/fonts

It works on my computer when I'm adding this code in .css file

```
@font-face {
font-family: MullerBlack;
src: url(/bildxwerkstatt/user/themes/bildxwerkstatt/fonts/Muller/MullerBlack.otf);}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-family: MullerBlack, sans-serif!important;}
```

However on the host such path does not work.

As I understood from the Grav documentation the path to font in css should looks like this:

```
url(theme:fonts/Muller/MullerBlack.otf);}
```

But it does not work in my case. The same problem I have when trying to add background image in css.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With the given information it is difficult to help.

`bildxwerkstatt` is a folder in the document root but also the theme name, right?

The first thing to check is if you have the provided `.htaccess` and set the `RewriteBase`. See [Grav Troubleshooting 404 Not Found](https://learn.getgrav.org/16/troubleshooting/page-not-found)

Then you should check your css syntax.

```css
@import url('https://...
```

or with `base.html.twiq`

```html
<link href="https://...
```

From [Grav Asset Manager](https://learn.getgrav.org/15/themes/asset-manager) about Static Assets:

> The url() method takes an optional second parameter of true or false to enable the URL to include the schema and domain.

Also check the available [Theme Variables](https://learn.getgrav.org/16/themes/theme-vars).

> The `{{ theme_url }}` returns the relative URL to the current theme.

And here an example how i set a background image for the specific page:

```
{% set background_image = page.media.images|randomize|first %}
{% set background_image = background_image.name.cache.url %}

<div {% if background_image %} style="background-image: url({{ background_image }})"{% endif %}></div>
```